# Clear background for modalPresentationStyle declared as 'formsheet'

Tags: ios, uimodalpresentationstyle

I want to set a clear background for `modalPresentationStyle` declared as `formSheet`.

[image]

Is it possible to customize?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to customize the background color for modalPresentationStyle(formsheet)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958063/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-background-color-for-modalpresentationstyleform)

Comment: Please do not repost your questions. Please edit your previous question as needed and delete this one.

Comment: I have deleted my previous post